# How do i span in gridlayout but in android java class?

Tags: java, android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

Im doing a schedule for my school using Android, and i did the schedule via gridlayout,but now i cant rowSpan or columnSpan using the java part.

And the result is:

[Image of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFXcs.png)

Here is the code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/hora"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:columnCount="14"
    android:rowCount="12">

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 1" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/hour2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:text="Hora 2" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 3" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 4" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 5" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 6" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 7" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 8" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 9" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/hour10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="10"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="Hora 10" />


    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:text="Dia 1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day2"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:text="Dia 2"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day3"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:text="Dia 3"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day4"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:text="Dia 4"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day5"
        android:layout_column="9"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:text="Dia 5"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day6"
        android:layout_column="11"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:text="Dia 6"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/tableBG"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/day1time1D"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text=" DISC " />
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/tableBG"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day2time5D"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:text=" DISC " />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/tableBG"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day2time5S"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:text=" SALA " />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/tableBG"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day2time6D"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:text=" DISC " />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/tableBG"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day2time6S"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:text=" SALA " />

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/tableBG"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/day2time7D"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:text=" DISC " />
```

etc...
I had to cut some code cuz overflow doesnt allow me to put all at the same time

What i want its use the Span commands on java, Can anyone help me? If there is any other way that do the same please tell me. Thank you